# body_class hook for admin pages

Tags: plugin-development, admin

The body_class hook seem only to work with non-admin pages.  When I do

```
add_filter('body_class', 'add_body_classes');
function add_body_classes($classes) {
        $classes[] = 'myclass';
        return $classes;
}
```

Is there another hook i should be using if i want to add a class to the body of an admin page?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Admin pages don't use the `body_class` filter, use the `admin_body_class` filter to add classes to admin body tag instead.

Note that `$classes` in that case is a string, not an array.

Comment: It's worth noting that the $classes parameter in the method for the admin_body_class filter is a string and not an array https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_body_class/

Comment: I wish @Mamaduka would write that comment into the answer. I just tore down an entire site, before I noticed Romans comment.

Answer (score 17):

[Mamaduka](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/888/mamaduka) [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/44447/17187) pointed me [to the right direction](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/2f513d332040073467f279dfdc2af6a63f7c2cae/wp-admin/admin-header.php#L161-L173), here is the code for adding classes to the body in the dashboard.

The callback function should return a valid value for the HTML class attribute, that is space separated class names, also, don't forget to prepend (or append) any existing classes, you should understand by reading the code.

```
add_filter( 'admin_body_class', 'my_admin_body_class' );

/**
 * Adds one or more classes to the body tag in the dashboard.
 *
 * @link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/154951/17187
 * @param  String $classes Current body classes.
 * @return String          Altered body classes.
 */
function my_admin_body_class( $classes ) {
    return "$classes my_class";
    // Or: return "$classes my_class_1 my_class_2 my_class_3";
}
```

Comment: This should probably be the selected answer. Asker's original implementation returns an array, but the hook accepts a space-separated string: [https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_body_class/](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_body_class/). Selected answer is therefore misleading, as it only partially answers the question and provides no reference.

Comment: To make PHP more easy to implement if you are not a programmer, without using _strings inside doubble quotes_ are the same as `return $classes.' my-class my-other-class';`

Comment: I use `return sprintf('%s folded', $classes);` as per my convenience.

Answer (score 1):

Adding multiple classes, and especially when they must display based on some conditions, may result in an inconsistent HTML output.
To format it correctly and also have the ability to remove duplicates or existing classes, we can convert them to array and in the end join back to string:

```
add_filter('admin_body_class', static function ($classes) {
    $classes = explode(' ', $classes);
    
    $classes = array_merge($classes, [
        'my-class-one',
        'my-class-two',
        'my-class-three',
        some_function(),
        another_function(),
    ]);

    return implode(' ', array_unique($classes));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

one of the hooks i use for editing WP admin/Dashboard admin_head

```
    function remove_screen_options(){ 

    $hideCSS = '<style>#screen-meta-links { display: none; }</style>';

}
```

Will put the css in your admin  part

And by using class .wp-admin you could style the body part of admin.

Good luck