# Add post id as body class in wordpress admin dashboard

Tags: posts, body-class

i am looking to add custom class names to the body tag of all our posts (including pages, posts, Woocommerce products) all have post id's (seen in the URL when editing a post, category, etc.) and is also part of the body class on the front end.

How do i also add it to the body class when for example "editing the post" in the dashboard. So i can call it via our admin.css

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just in case you missed the message above like I did the first time, you can find the answer here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44444/body-class-hook-for-admin-pages. There's the `admin_body_class` filter that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to completely got your question, but if you are looking for a way to have in the editor the same classes you are using in the frontend, put an `editor-style.css` file in your child theme folder and fill it with the classes you need (i.e.:body). Then in your `functions.php`, add this line:

```
add_editor_style('editor-style.css');
```