# Adding body class to login page?

Tags: wp-admin, hooks, login, body-class

I can't figure out for the life of me how to add a custom body class to the WordPress login page. I found [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44444/body-class-hook-for-admin-pages), which suggests using the `admin_body_class` along with [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12863/check-if-wp-login-is-current-page/12865) to check if the current page is the login, and nothing seems to work. I have a multisite network going, and my ultimate aim is to add the `blog_id` number for each site to its corresponding login page as a body class- is this possible? This is one approach I've tried, to no avail:

```
function login_body_class($classes) {     
    global $blog_id;

    if ( $GLOBALS['pagenow'] === 'wp-login.php' ) {
        $append = ' ' . $blog_id . ' ';
        $classes .= $append;
    }
    return $classes;
}

add_filter('admin_body_class', 'login_body_class');
```

(Given that `admin_body_class` takes a string and not an array, I've added in spaces before/after the class name.) Thanks for any insight here!

Comment: Take a careful read of the answers and comments on the pages you linked to, and look at the dates. Some are quite old, and plausibly no longer work. But there are also newer answers, and comments, which sound like worth following.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're on the right track with a filter. Have you tried `login_body_class` *as the filter?*

```php
function add_blog_id_to_login_page( $classes ) {
    $blog_id   = get_current_blog_id();
    $classes[] = "blog-{$blog_id}";
    return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'login_body_class', 'add_blog_id_to_login_page' );
```

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't realize that hook existed!! Thank you @phatskat

Comment: No problem! The easiest way to start finding the hooks and actions you need is to open the file - in this case, I opened `/wp-login.php` and searched for `<body`, and found the filter a few lines above. Never touch core, but don't be afraid to look around ;)