# Can't add script immediately after the opening <body> tag on login page?

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to add the following Google Tag Manager script immediately after the opening `<body>` tag on the Wordpress login page.

**Code that I want to insert**

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

**What I have tried**

Based on the solution given here: [Adding body class to login page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/333178/adding-body-class-to-login-page), I tried the following code:

```
function my_custom_code2($classes){
?>
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-P3CWDSQ"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->";
<?php 
}

add_filter( 'login_body_class', 'my_custom_code2' );
```

**Results**

It does not work. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

**In response to Sally's query below, this is the full code I am using.**

```
function my_custom_code1(){
?>
 
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->";

<?php 
}
add_action( 'login_head', 'my_custom_code1', 10 );
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> immediately after the opening `<body>` tag

WordPress doesn't provide a hook for that, i.e. for adding code *exactly* after the `<body>` tag.

But WordPress does fire a hook named [`login_header`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_header/) which we can use to add code after the `body` tag is opened:

> `do_action( 'login_header' )`
>  Fires in the login page header after
> the body tag is opened.

So for example:

```php
add_action( 'login_header', 'wpse_375598' );
function wpse_375598() {
    ?>
        Add your HTML here.
    <?php
}
```

And BTW, `login_body_class` is a *filter* hook one can use to add custom CSS classes into the `<body>` tag (i.e. `<body class="here">`), so that hook should not be used to add the (Google Tag Manager's) `noscript` code.

Also in the edited question, the problem is that you used [`login_head`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_head/) and not `login_header` — `login_head` is for adding code in the `<head>` section of the document/page.

So your code should look more like:

```php
add_action( 'login_head', 'wpse_375598_login_head' );
function wpse_375598_login_head() {
    ?>
        Add your HTML here that goes in the <head>.
    <?php
}

add_action( 'login_header', 'wpse_375598_login_header' );
function wpse_375598_login_header() {
    ?>
        Add your HTML here that goes in the <body>.
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sally, but doesn't that add items to the `header` instead of the `body`? I tried your method and I get this error message for Google Tag Manager "GTM no-script code not found: either missing or not in <body>".

Comment: The docs says, "*Fires in the login page header **after the body tag is opened**.*", so the hook does fire in the document body. However, if you mean *exactly* after the `<body>` tag, then I'm afraid there's no hook available for that.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out Sally. Would you mind having a look at my site: https://rebrand.ly/sallycj

It still shows that the code is being deployed before the body tag (https://i.imgur.com/ByA0ddi.png)

Comment: Can you show the PHP code you used? Add it in the question or put it on Pastebin.com.

Comment: Thanks, Sally, I have inserted the full code in the question. It is at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks Sally! It worked :)